# Finding equal lines in file with Perl

Tags: perl

I have a CSV file which contains duplicated items in different rows.

```
x1,y1
x2,y2
y1,x1
x3,y3
```

The two rows containing `x1,y1` and `y1,x1` are a match as they contain the same data in a diffrent order.

I need your help to find an algorithm to search for such lines in a 12MB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define some ordering and equality relations between fields, you could store a normalized form and test your lines for equality against that.

As an example, we will use string comparision for your fields, but after lowercasing them. We can then sort the parts according to this relation, and create a lookup table via a nested hash:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $cache; # A hash of hashes. Will be autovivified later.

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split;

  # create the normalized representation by lowercasing and sorting the fields
  my @normalized_fields = sort map lc, @fields;

  # find or create the path in the lookup
  my $pointer = \$cache;
  $pointer = \${$pointer}->{$_} for @normalized_fields;

  # if this is an unknow value, make it known, and output the line
  unless (defined $$pointer) {
    $$pointer = 1; # set some defined value
    print "$_\n"; # emit the unique line
  }
}

__DATA__
X1 y1
X2 y2
Y1 x1
X3 y3
```

In this example I used the scalar `1` as value of the lookup data structure, but in more complex scenarios the original fields or the line number could be stored here. For the sake of the example, I used space-seperated values here, but you could replace the `split` with a call to `Text::CSV` or something.

This hash-of-hashes approach has sublinear space complexity, and worst case linear space complexity. The lookup time only depends on the number (and size) of fields in a record, not on the total number of records.

**Limitation:** All records *must* have the same number of fields, or some shorter records could be falsely considered “seen”. To circumvent these problems, we can use more complex nodes:

```
  my $pointer = \$cache;
  $pointer = \$$pointer->[0]{$_} for @normalized_fields;

  unless (defined $$pointer->[1]) {
    $$pointer->[1] = 1; ...
  }
```

or introduce a default value for nonexistant field (e.g. the seperator of the original file). Here an example with the NUL character:

```
 my $fields = 3;
 ...;
 die "record too long" if @fields > $fields;
 ...; # make normalized fields
 push @normalized_fields, ("\x00") x ($fields - @normalized_fields);
 ...; # do the lookup
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on what you want to know about duplicate lines once they have been found. This program uses a simple hash to list the line numbers of those lines that are equivalent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my $key = join ',', sort map lc, split /,/;
  push @{$data{$key}}, $.;
}

foreach my $list (values %data) {
  next unless @$list > 1;
  print "Lines ", join(', ', @$list), " are equivalent\n";
}

__DATA__
x1,y1
x2,y2
y1,x1
x3,y3
```

**output**

```
Lines 1, 3 are equivalent
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make two hash tables `A` and `B`
2. Stream through your input one line at a time
3. For the first line pair `x` and `y`, use each as key and the other as value for both hash tables (e.g., `$A->{x} = y; $B->{y} = x;`)
4. For the second and subsequent line pairs, test if the second field's value exists as a key for either `A` or `B` — if it does, you have a reverse match — if not, then repeat the addition process from step 3 to add it to the hash tables

Comment: I forgot to note that the values in the fields are not unique, but the couple of values are: x1 is not unique , but x1y1 is unique. So if I make hashtable $A{x} and $B{y} - I will loose some values.

Comment: In that case, perhaps use the concatenations `x1y1` and `y1x1` as keys (since those are going to be unique identifiers), and test second and subsequent lines for existence of either key combination.

Answer (score 0):

To do a version of amon's answer without a hash table, if your data are numerical, you could:

1. Stream through input line by line, sorting fields one and two by numerical ordering
2. Pipe result to UNIX `sort` on first and second fields
3. Stream through sorted output line by line, checking if current line matches the previous line (reporting a reverse match, if true)

This has the advantage of using less memory than hash tables, but may take more time to process.

Answer (score 0):

amon already provided the answer I would've provided, so please enjoy this bad answer:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use common::sense;

my $re = qr/(?!)/;  # always fails

while (<DATA>) {
  warn "Found duplicate: $_" if $_ =~ $re;
  next unless /^(.*),(.*)$/;
  die "Unexpected input at line $.: $_" if "$1$2" =~ tr/,//;
  $re = qr/^\Q$2,$1\E$|$re/
}

__DATA__
x1,y1
x2,y2
y1,x1
x3,y3
```